# How do I host my Google App Engine App as a site at my domain?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, web, google-cloud-platform

Background:
My app is a single-page HTML form that has the fields "Name", "Email", "Phone", then a drop-down box with 3 options, and lastly a "please contact me" checkbox. I created it with create-react-app, then made a production build, then added an app.yaml file using the configuration instructions from Google Cloud Platform. I then pushed the build folder and app.yaml file to my remote GitHub repo, and then used the Google Cloud Shell to clone that GitHub repo into Google App Engine.

I deployed my app, and google gave me the link to view my app in my browser, the myproject.ue.r.appspot.com link.

Now I want to:

1. Host my app (the form) at the domain I already own through google domains.

Your help and patience is greatly appreciated

Below is a screenshot of my app, basically a single-page contact-us form.

Comment: Limit your question to one problem. You have specified two unrelated questions - Domain Names and Database. Create another question and edit this one. How is the screenshot related to your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domain.

Set your custom domain and you will have the record to add to Google Domains

[image]

*If you never register your domain on Google cloud, follow the instructions and add a technical record to validate the registration.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!